# подстрока в строке PHP?

Tags: php

Есть у меня строка, например "Рога и копыта отзывы". мне необходимо средствами PHP получить из нее строку без слова "отзывы". Мой код:

```
$string = 'Рога и копыта отзывы';
if(stristr($string, 'отзывы') === FALSE) {
    echo '"отзывы" не найдена в строке';
}else{
    $string = stristr($string, 'отзывы',true);
    echo $string;
}
```

Получается что если слово "отзывы" находится в конце строки, то возвращает то что мне нужно, а если в начале, то не возвращает ничего. Как можно решить эту проблему.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно в одну строку решить:

```
$string = 'Рога и копыта отзывы';
$need = 'отзывы';

!preg_match("/$need/", $string) ?: print "'$need' найдена в строке";
```

И тогда, если искомое слово `'отзывы'` есть в строке, то в браузере вы увидите сообщение: `'отзывы' найдена в строке`.

---

А для удаления слова из любой части строки, можно использовать preg_replace():

```
$string = ' отзывы Рога и копыта';
$need = 'отзывы';

echo preg_replace("/\s?$need\s?/", '', $string); // Рога и копыта
```

Comment: Спасибо! жирное решение!

Answer (score 0):

Можно конечно сделать это через `preg_match`, но самый простой метод использовать `str_replace`:

```
<?php
   $string = 'Рога и копыта отзывы';
   $str = trim(str_replace('отзывы','',$string));
   echo $str;
?>
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74792/discussion-on-answer-by-arsen----php).